# Spring Batch - Connection closed in when processing is done in external process

Tags: java, spring-batch, database-metadata

- I have a job that is built of several steps - one of the steps is a tasklet that activates processing Pentaho
- I pass to Pentaho the parameters it needs in order to connect to the DB on its own and it works OK
- The issue I have starts when the processing time in Pentaho is long
- Pentaho completes successfully and the code in the tasklet that activated it completes OK, but in the job mechanism that wraps it I get an error when it tries to update the job execution table in the db because the connection it has was already closed

  ```
   o.s.j.s.SQLErrorCodesFactory: Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; 
   nested exception is         
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:141)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
       at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:230)
       at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:159)
       at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:203)
   ...
   14:21:37.143 UTC [ERROR] jobScheduler_Worker-2 T:b U: o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor: Application exception overridden by rollback exception
   org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE BAT_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; Communications link failure
  ```
- It looks like the connection that the job repository received when the job started was abandoned and I'm trying to understand if there is a way to order it get a new connection or give it some keep alive command

I tried the following workarounds

- change the step status in a job listener so the job will complete - fails with the same DB error
- mark this exception as if it can be skipped - fails with the same DB error

  ```
   <batch:no-rollback-exception-classes>
     <batch:include class="com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException" />
     <batch:include class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException" />
   </batch:no-rollback-exception-classes>
  ```

Any ideas how I can work around this?

Can I configure a job listener that will restart the job from the step that follows the Pentaho step?

**Additional info**
I think that the issue is here -
`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSource)`

This

```
    ConnectionHolder conHolder = (ConnectionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(dataSource);
```

thinks that the connection is valid

so I guess the solution will be to call `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(Object)`

and the question is how can I get the **data source** object to pass to this method

I will try querying the
`org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap()` and see where it gets me

**update**
no luck - the get resources map gives me just the repositories I'm using, not the data source. Still digging...

**Another update**

I'm debugging the process and it seems that the problem is indeed `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSource)` the connection holder is holding a connection that is closed but the code here doesn't check if the connection is open; it only checks if the connection isn't null and if it was some weak reference maybe it was enough here - but in this use case it just proceedes with the closed connection instead of requesting a new one.

Comment: I keep updating the question with my findings and i get no responses - is there any point in keeping this updated?

Comment: Probably because the problem is rare? At least, it helps some people i guess. I have the same issue with long running jobs longer than the `wait_timeout` mysql parameter. (By default its 8 hours or so) Not with tasklets but with the chunk processing when each chunk takes hours or days of computation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to the tasklet definition

```
<batch:transaction-attributes propagation="NEVER" />
```

since the Tasklet is doing external processing and doesn't need a spring batch transaction it need to tell spring batch not to open a transaction for this tasklet.

see 
http://www.javabeat.net/transaction-management-in-spring-batch-components/
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/91158-legacy-integration-tasklet-transaction

Comment: You might elaborate: why does this fix the problem?